# Problems animating labels and textfield (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm having problems with the animation of labels and textfield. The labels just disappear and the text fields don't do anything. I don't know why, but with buttons i have no problem. Think missing something really stupid. Well here is what a i have tried for labels:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{label.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1,1);}];
```

For text fields:

```
UITextField *box = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{box.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1,1);}];
```

What i'm missing?

Comment: are they running on the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGRectMake(0,0,1,1)` is going to be a really small box. They're not disappearing, you're shoving it all into one pixel. Try something more reasonable, like `CGRectMake(0,0,100,50)` and see if that works.

`CGRectMake` is defined as:

```
CGRect CGRectMake (
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y,
   CGFloat width,
   CGFloat height
);
```

so you were setting the width and height to 1.

If you just want to move the center without resizing, try this.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{label.center = CGPointMake(x,y);}];
```

where x and y are the coordinates of the new center.

Comment: you were right, i think that you can't do CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) with labels because the text don't can't be contained in a too small space, and that is why disappear. However, I can't make it work with the textfield yet :/. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: try moving the center like I suggested in the post. Does that work?

Comment: I got it, the code that i post on the question is together, and as both have tag:1, that was causing troubles. i changed the tag of the textfield to 2 and it worked. Thanks :).